# Getting out byte instead of byte* in UWP from my C++/CLI delegate

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, c++-cli, byte

My mainproject is a UWP App and I'm using a C++ DLL. To use the DLL I wrote a C++/CLI (I think) Wrapper Class.
My problem is that I'm getting an `out byte` as Parameter insteat of `byte*`in a defined `Delegate`.

**Wrapper Class:**

```
// Definition of the Delegate I want to use
// pBinaryData is defined as byte* am I right?
public delegate bool ReceiveRawDelegate(unsigned int nIndex, unsigned int nSender, unsigned int nSize, unsigned char* pBinaryData);
```

**UWP Class**

```
// Using the Delegate from the Wrapper Class
_pInterface.EnableRawData(new CheckRawMessageDelegate(CheckRawData), new ReceiveRawDelegate(OnChanelReceiveRaw));

// The method the Delegate calls
// pBinaryData becomes an out byte but I want a byte* like in the Wrapper Delegate
unsafe bool OnChanelReceiveRaw(uint nIndex, uint nSender, uint nSize, out byte pBinaryData) {...}
```

The idea with this delegate is, that I get picture information as byte* from the DLL that I want to use in my UWP Project. The DLL is not under my development, so I don't realy know hot it works. Normaly the `pBinaryData` should by a pointer to that picture data, but in some way UWP converts the `byte*` into a `out byte` type and I can't work with the `out byte` type.

I hope my problem is clear. Please let me know if more code is needed.

Thanks to all.

Comment: So, change it to `out byte*`?

Comment: If I change `OnChanelReceiveRaw` to use `out byte*` I'm getting type missmatch of parameter, because teh delegate gives me a `out byte` and my method wants a `out byte*`. And C++/CLI doesn't know the `out` type.

Comment: The C++/CLI is used in the desktop platform which should not be used here as a wrapper? Did you have a typo here? Can you provide us the steps about how you create the wrapper?